# Add Datepicker Function dynamically

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have such input with `class="datepicker"`. I insert calendar throught js `$('.datepicker').datepicker()`; I have another js, which copy this input throught `.clone()`. But for new element datepicker doesn't work. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: try to use different id for datepicker input

Answer (score 0):

You need to `clone()` the element then re-initialise the datepicker on it, for example:

```
$('.datepicker').clone().appendTo('#foo').datepicker();
```

Alternatively you can clone the element and keep the events it has attached to it. Note that this method may not work as it depends on how the datepicker element creates the supporting HTML elements it needs. I've not tested it personally.

```
$('.datepicker').clone(true, true).appendTo('#foo');
```